# How to leave prompt when accidentally enter Grave accent character?

Tags: prompt

If I write Grave accent character in the terminal, my prompt becomes `bquote`:

[image]

and I cannot leave it in anyway. How can I leave this prompt?

Comment: Try `Ctrl-C` or `Ctrl-D`.

Comment: ctrl-c it is :)

Comment: yea lol :D :D ctrl-c worked! what is this btw?? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can press control-c to exit

[image]

Comment: I tried everything (ctrl+z) included, but yeah ctrl+c worked! Thanks.